# Check if a Kafka topic had ever received any data

Tags: apache-kafka

I have an empty topic right now, I don't know if there was some data in it before. I've checked the offset with this command:

```
./kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell \
    --bootstrap-server myserver:9072 \
    --topic mytopic
```

It shows the offset as 0. My question is, that means there was never data in this topic? Do offsets get reset when older data are removed? Like, is there a possibility for a data with offset 12 to be newer than a data with offset 25?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offsets never decrease with retention, no.

While you didn't specify it, `--time -1` is the default  arguement (latest offset), so that does mean the topic is empty.